# How can I use \texttt{some text} for the names of greek letters?

Tags: fonts, greek, letters, typewriter

I want to write coefficients names as alpha_0, beta_1 and phi_1 using \texttt{...} to make it look like a function arguments.

I tried `\texttt{alpha_0}` but I got an error `! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ \item \texttt{alpha_0}`. Based on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tex_commands/texttt.htm I have tried also `\texttt{\alpha_0}`, `\texttt{$\alpha_0$}` or even similar name `\texttt{alfa_0}` but nothing worked for me.

Comment: The problem is the underscore which starts subscript in maths and isn't allowed outside of it. You should use `\_` instead.

Comment: @Skillmon, thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify if you want `alpha` written like this or you want the Greek letter? The question is a bit unclear.

Comment: I want it like this: \texttt{alpha\ _0} corresponds to ```alpha_0```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the names and the underscore

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\mathtt{alpha\_1}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the Greek letters

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathgtt}{LGR}{cmtt}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

$\mathgtt{a_1}$
$\mathgtt{b_1}$
$\mathgtt{f_1}$

\end{document}
```

The picture also shows the conversion table (some characters are not easily predictable).

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the 1. option - the names and the underscore, was the one that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an underscore, you must write it in text mode as `\_`.  You also need to select a text font that supports Greek letters, such as New Computer Modern Mono or CMU Typewriter Text.

To use `\alpha` in text mode, you can load `\usepackage{alphabeta}`.  You can also get `\textalpha` from `\usepackage{alphabeta}` or `\usepackage{textgreek}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup} % Sets the text and math fonts to New Computer Modern Book.
\usepackage{alphabeta} % Allows \alpha, etc. in text mode.

\newcommand\param[1]{\textnormal{\ttfamily #1}}

\begin{document}
\( \param{\alpha\_0} \, \param{\beta\_1} \, \param{\phi\_1}
\)
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern Mono sample]

An alternative is to use the `\mathtt` alphabet.

If you want the underscores to be subscripts, you can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup} % Sets the text and math fonts to New Computer Modern Book.

\newcommand\param[1]{\mathtt{#1}}

\begin{document}
\( \param{\mupalpha_0} \, \param{\mupbeta_1} \, \param{\mupvarphi_1}
\)
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern Mono sample]

The correct symbol names to use are from [this manual,](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) but loading `\usepackage{textgreek}` and using `\textalpha`, etc. in math mode will work too.

For `\mathtt` to work in 8-bit legacy PDFTeX, you would need to find (or create) a typewriter font in OML encoding and load it with `isomath`.  That is the only legacy TeX encoding that supports both the Greek and Latin alphabets.  If you’ve loaded an 8-bit LGR font and can write `\textnormal{\ttfamily\selectfont\alpha}` or `\textnormal{\ttfamily\selectfont\textalpha}` in text mode, the same command will work in math mode as well.